# makefile assign command to

Tags: makefile, freebsd

I'm probably being stupid, but I cannot do the most basic variable assignment in my Makefile.

```
TEST = $(pwd);

all:
    echo $(TEST)
```

When I run "make all" from Bash (v4.2.42) in FreeBSD (v9.1) I get:

```
echo
```

No idea what I'm screwing up. I've also tried to assign the variable using $(shell ...) with the same result.

If I use back ticks (`) then basic assignment works, but it doesn't store the result, it stores the command. This breaks in the following example Makefile:

```
SERVERIP = `ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $$2}'`

all:
    echo $(SERVERIP)
    sed -e 's/%LISTENIP%/${SERVERIP}/g' test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
```

The result is:

```
[pete@pete] ~/make
echo `ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2}'`
10.128.28.151
sed -e 's/%LISTENIP%/`ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $2}'`/g' test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
sed: 1: "s/%LISTENIP%/`ifconfig  ...": unescaped newline inside substitute pattern
*** [all] Error code 1
```

You can see that basic variable assignment appears to work, but when you insert the result into sed, it inserts the whole command rather than the result, which breaks!

Any ideas?

Pete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The makefile contains:

```
TEST = $(pwd);

all:
    echo $(TEST)
```

The first line assigns the value in the `make` variable `pwd` plus a semicolon to `make` variable `TEST`.  The rule then echoes that.  You forgot, I think, that `$(...)` is significant to both `make` and `shell`.  Assuming you want to echo the output of the `pwd` command, then use a double-dollar so `make` expands that to one dollar:

```
TEST = $$(pwd)

all:
    echo $(TEST)
```

---

To get the output of a shell command into a `make` variable, you have to use GNU `make` extensions.  There are two extensions in use: the `:=` immediate assignment that evaluates the value of `SERVERIP` at the point of definition, rather than at the point of use; and `$(shell ...cmd...)` that is used to run a shell command and capture its output.

```
SERVERIP := $(shell ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $$2}')

all:
    echo ${SERVERIP}
    sed -e 's/%LISTENIP%/${SERVERIP}/g' test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
```

This should work.  The original error, about a newline in the `sed` regular expression, is odd; the back-ticks should have removed the trailing newline from the output of the `ifconfig` pipeline.  However, if there were in fact multiple lines returned, then you'd still have a newline inside, justifying the complaint from `sed`.

This generates the complaint:

```
SERVERIP = `printf "%s\n" a b c`

all:
    echo $(SERVERIP)
    sed -e "s/%LISTENIP%/${SERVERIP}/g" test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
```

This works:

```
SERVERIP = `printf "%s\n" c`

all:
    echo $(SERVERIP)
    sed -e "s/%LISTENIP%/${SERVERIP}/g" test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
```

---

Since you're using FreeBSD, it is quite possible that you don't have GNU `make`.  In that case, you will need to:

1. Make sure the `ifconfig` command pipeline only produces one line of output.
2. Use `make` commands like this:

   ```
   SERVERIP = `ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $$2}'`

   all:
       echo ${SERVERIP}
       sed -e "s/%LISTENIP%/${SERVERIP}/g" test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
   ```

   That should work with any version of `make` provided condition 1 is met.

Comment: I tested this on the second example (sed) but it doesn't actually provide the value of the command but rather the command itself, which breaks sed. I.e. same result as above.

Comment: Thanks mate for that. I copied the := example but unfortunately it echoes out a blank line and sed replaces the LISTENIP token with nothing.

Comment: You're on FreeBSD?  Maybe you don't have GNU `make`?  I did point out that the solution was using GNU `make` extensions to `make`.

Comment: Yeah I'm using GNU Make. Didn't realise that there was a difference between GNU and BSD make. Anyway, according to pkg_info it's gmake-3.82

Comment: And when you ran `make --version`, it confirmed GNU make?

Comment: I get an illegal option error :) But I just ran gmake all instead of make all and it worked fine. Thanks so much for your help mate. Saved my bacon!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the answer is too late but I hope I can help (somebody else).

If you don't want to install GNU's `make` you can use the `!=`:

```
TEST!=pwd
all:
    echo ${TEST}
```

will work. The explanation is very simple, please read carefully [FreeBSD's man make](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?make(1)), especially the ***"Variable assignment modifiers"*** inside the ***"VARIABLE ASSIGNMENTS"*** section:

> Variable assignment modifiers
>
> The five operators that can be used to assign values to variables are
>   as follows: ...
>
> !=      Expand the value and pass it to the shell for execution and
>                assign the result to the variable.  Any newlines in the result
>                are replaced with spaces.

Comment: Nice one! I didn't know that. Better late than never :) Thanks.

Comment: THANK YOU!! That helped me with a complex octave dependency in a new Port for FreeBSD =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a test makefile, similar to yours. The `ifconfig` command has been placed in a $(shell ...) command and the result is stored in `SERVERIP`.

```
TOP:= $(shell pwd)
SERVERIP:= $(shell ifconfig en1 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $$2}')
LISTENIP:=240.12.4.63

all:
     echo $(SERVERIP)
     sed -e 's/$(LISTENIP)/$(SERVERIP)/g' test.conf > work/test.conf.tmp
```

Comment: I copied this exactly into a blank Makefile but echo $(SERVERIP) didn't actually produce any output. If I run the command in the shell it does return an IP. Could this be an eccentricity in my server configuration?

Comment: Oh I think just that my network interface name is different to yours. Sorry I forgot to change it back to your interface name. Yours em0 mine en1.

Comment: Yep I changed that, but still no joy. Running the Makefile below returns a blank line (after showing the echo command itself):

@SERVERIP = $$(ifconfig em0 | grep -E 'inet.[0-9]' | awk '{ print $$2}')

all:
        echo $(SERVERIP)

Comment: Oops! I stuffed that up. Sorry, it does echo the IP when I don't include @ before assigning SERVERIP. My bad, sorry! However if I try running sed then it gives me the command string, not the value of the command.

Comment: In your prev message you had $$(ifconfig.... - could it be that? Should be $(ifconfig ...   Also what version of make are you using? I'm on GNU make v3.81. I noticed Jonathan has amended his solution - perhaps that solve your problem.

Comment: Running make -VMAKE_VERSION gave me 9201120530. Is that meaningful to you??

Comment: Possibly your version of make does not support $(shell ...) commands. If you are still having problems later on today I will take another look.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help mate. You were onto the same thing. Gmake fixed my troubles.